# Angular js solve a different format of a json array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, object

Based on the  result below , how can an angular for each loop be able to solve that json array of objects format ? The value is title and the id is key. Any Idea? Thank you.

## mycode

```
me.record.questionaires = []
angular.forEach(detail.questionaires, function (value, key) {
            me.record.questionaires.push({ "id": key, "title": value })

        });
```

## Formated json data (detail.questionaire result)

```
[  
   "{'sub_title': 'dsadsa', 'instruction': 'You Must',…elimit': '01:05:19', 'title': 'asdsa', 'id': 133}",
   "{'sub_title': 'sdasdsa', 'instruction': None, 'cre…melimit': '05:30:09', 'title': 'asda', 'id': 131}"
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to

1. Loop  over the array
2. Parse the string as JSON
3. Push or map the appropriate values into your `questionaires` array (it's not clear what data you want)

```js
me.record.questionaires = detail.questionaires.map(json => {
  let { id, title } = JSON.parse(json)
  return { id, title }
})
```

Comment: nexpected token ' in JSON at position 1

Comment: @JhonCaylog well that's because your _"formatted JSON data"_ is not JSON. Where does it come from? If you're manually typing it out, you should get the syntax correct (keys and string values must be quoted with double-quotes)

Answer (score 1):

I had to change your sample formatted JSON a bit because it was giving me console errors. Please see if this helps.

```js
angular
  .module("myModule", [])
  .controller("myController", function($scope) {
    var me ={record: {questionaires: []}};
    $scope.me = me;
 
    var detail ={};
    detail.questionaires = [  
      "{'sub_title': 'dsadsa', 'instruction': 'You Must','…elimit': '01:05:19', 'title': 'asdsa', id: 133}",
      '{"sub_title": "sdasdsa", "instruction": "None", "cre…melimit": "05:30:09", "title": "asda", "id": 131}'
    ];

    angular.forEach(detail.questionaires, function (value, key) {
    
      var questionaire = JSON.parse(value.replace(/'/g, '"').replace(/id:/g, '"id":'));     
      me.record.questionaires.push({ "id": questionaire.id, "title": questionaire.title });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
  <div><strong>me.record.questionaires:</strong></div>
    <div ng-repeat="q in me.record.questionaires">
    <div>{{q}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The properties and values have to have double quotes instead of single quotes, and you had None without quotes... I am not sure if you meant to use null there instead or "None"

Comment: but that data is detail.questionaire

Comment: ang examplel ["{'department': "Don't Let Me Down", 'sub_title': '…91111011211', 'timelimit': '01:05:01', 'id': 175}"]

Comment: is there a way we can change it w

Comment: See update answer. Use regular expression to replace all the single quotes for double quotes

Comment: bro im still receiving Unexpected token t in JSON at position 20

Comment: here is an example data {id: 0, title: "{'department': "Don't Let Me Down", 'sub_title': '…91111011211', 'timelimit': '01:05:01', 'id': 175}"}

Comment: Oh my, event if you were to replace all the single quotes for double quotes, you have still to find a way to wrap that first id in quotes, but not with replace since it doesn't have single quotes. And additionally you already have an 'id' at the end of the data. You cannot have two keys with the same name. I strongly recommend you to go back to the source from where you are getting this JSON and fix that first so you receive it in the proper format.

Comment: so there no other solution other than that?

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but to me the data you are receiving is messed up, you cannot have duplicate keys in JSON.

Comment: how about we just get the title and forget the id ?

Comment: Try the latest edit, if it finds duplicate id's it will use the last that it will find (even if it is not inside quotes)